# Eclipse: import multiple gradle git projects

Tags: eclipse, gradle, import

We are working with multiple git projects, each of them is a Gradle project. When we start a new environment, let's say a fresh eclipse installation, we need to import each gradle project manually through **File -> Import -> Gradle -> Existing Gradle Project** to correctly import them into eclipse workspace with their gradle tasks.

Is there a way to tell eclipse to import them all at once? (Obviously **File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace** doesn't solve this question)

Comment: In the _Git Repositories_ view right-click the Git repository and choose _Import Projects..._.

Comment: excuse me, I'm not sure if I understood your comment. Each Gradle project is a independent git repository

Comment: I did import all the projects in the "Git Repositories view" as you recommended. But I don't see them imported inside the Project Explorer... I could import them one by one (but that's not the solution I'm looking for) and they will not be Gradle configurated projects.

Comment: If you use _File > Import Open Files from File System..._ you can choose the directory that contains the Git repositories. Unfortunately, the detection of Gradle projects is not yet implemented (see [this not yet closed issue](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/356)).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these Steps:

1. Select Import Existing Projects
2. Select a Directory that contains all the Projects under it
3. Click Option: ***Search For Nested Projects***
4. Click ***Finish***
5. This will Import all the Projects

Comment: Thank you @greencheese.
At the time I asked this question, I tried the solution you're mentioning without success.
Currently I'm not working with gradle projects, but I will try this solution when I find some time.
Look at this not yet closed issue: https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/356